# Will Android PeriodicWorkRequest stop working when app is updated?

Tags: android

If an Android app is updated automatically from Play Store, does `PeriodicWorkRequest` get canceled automatically?

For example, if I want to clean up some temporary files every 6 hours, does it mean the clean up task will be terminated whenever the app is updated?

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

Comment: No, it'll work fine because `WorkManager` API manages its own `database`,i.e., `androidx.work.workdb`, to handle and perform the various crucial operations including yours doubt. You can also check this `database` in `Android Studio` using [`App Inspection`](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database).

Comment: @MojoJojo Thanks! BTW can I access files in the application assets or data folder in a work request?

Comment: What files do you want to access in a work request or what's your requirement? Please elaborate.